# Silverlight PDF Form Editor

Tags: silverlight, pdf

Business Requirement:

I have some pdf forms that contain fields that I need the user to be able to edit/fill out in the browser using Silverlight.  Once the user is done with those edits, I need to be able to save the file client side.

Most controls that I have found so far only allow you to display and save a pdf, not edit/fill out.

Can anyone recommend a control that might satisfy this requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial library is an option for you, you could try with [Amyuni PDF for Silverlight](http://www.amyuni.com/en/server/pdfsilverlight/). It will allow you to fill out text fields on your PDF forms from Silverlight, you will be able to fill-in the resulting values into your PDF file in code-behind, then you can deliver your file to the client.

You can try it out [here](http://www.amyuni.ca/Silverlight4/), just select the file "sampleform.pdf" in the combobox. Only text fields are supported at the moment, radio-buttons and check-boxes will be added in a future release.

Amyuni PDF for Silverlight is based on two components, a server side control ([Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features) ActiveX or .Net) that converts the PDF into an XAML-based package, and a Silverlight viewer that is provided with source code.

Here is a screen capture:
[image]

More details about this component can be found at an [article in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374210/Editing-PDF-Forms-AcroForms-within-a-Silverlight-A).

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Comment: Have you used this control before with success?

Comment: can you provide some sample code for opening a pdf that will show editable text fields?

Comment: is this source code available with the demo?  Do you have plans to support SL 5? Will the library recognize fields on a form automatically or is that something I have to customize in order to work?

Comment: 1- Yes, source code for the Silverlight portion will be available, but not the server side PDF to XAML library. 2- The source code can be compiled in Silverlight 5 without changes. 3- The library will recognize text fields in PDF forms and provide them to you as text boxes in Silverlight. You will have to take care of retrieving the values entered by the user and submitting them to the server. A working sample project is provided for this.

Comment: yms, I'm not seeing this sample project in your downloads. the sample project that is provided does not even work / compile.

Comment: The sample project will be published in blog post at codeproject, and it's currently pending for their approval. I can send you my draft version if you provide me an email address. About the sample project on the website, it requires Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX or .Net to be installed. The project has references to both versions, so you should remove the reference to the version that you do not want to use, or you can install both for evaluation.

Comment: @strickland I posted the link. The sample code on the website has also been updated with the form-editing feature.